# How to implement a printf-like function in PHP?

Tags: php, printf

I want to make a `db_queryf` function for my database abstraction. It will work somewhat like `sqlite3_mprintf` from SQLite: `db_queryf('select * from pages where name=%q', $_GET['name'])`, where %q will produce a properly escaped string. What is the proper way of making printf-like functions in PHP? Is there any helper functions for that or I should parse it myself?

Comment: It is possible that you'd like to check [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/func_get_args), [`func_get_arg`](http://php.net/func_get_arg) and [`func_num_args`](http://php.net/func_num_args), but you'd have to parse the query string searching for `%like` placeholders, and it will possibly interfere where you'd want to use a `name LIKE '%foo%` query.

Comment: very viable, and underrated question... it's a shame the answers are ueseless though :( have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am confused... `(s)printf` plainly allready exists, and you probably want to use [`SQLite3Stmt::bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php) more for this, unless you want to end up in escaping / sql-injection hell..

Answer (score 1):

Use [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  Replacing into the string isn't good enough, you should be sanitizing.

Answer (score 0):

[`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
sprintf('select * from pages where name=\'%s\'', $_GET['name']);
```

Its *very* important, that you sanitize everything in `$_GET`, before you use it!

Comment: The whole point of db_query is not to sanitize everything. For example, db_query('select * where name=%q', "' and 1=1 --"); will produce select * where name='\' and 1=1 --'. Page with such a name obviously doesn't exist so the query will do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

okay, since I had exactly the same problem, I gave it a shot, and it seems to work quite nicely.

The following function sits inside a database wrapping class, and expects to be called like printf, where `%%` is transformed to a literal %, `%e` marks a string argument to be escaped, and `%u` marks a string argument to taken as-is.

`LOGDB` is a second database wrapping class, that is responsible for catching and logging all kinds of errors.

```
  public static function query($format)
  {
    $query = $format . ' ';

    $argc = func_num_args();
    $argv = func_get_args();

    $index_query = 0;
    $index_args = 1;

    while (($index_query = strpos($query, '%', $index_query)) !== false)
      {
        switch ($query[$index_query + 1])
          {
          case '%':
            $query = substr_replace($query, '', $index_query, 1);
            $index_query++;
            break;
          case 'e':
            if ($index_args >= $argc)
              {
                LOG::failedQuery($format, "not enough arguments for format");
                return false;
              }
            $query = substr_replace($query, DB::escape($argv[$index_args]), $index_query, 2);
            $index_query += strlen($argv[$index_args]);
            $index_args++;
            break;
          case 'u':
            if ($index_args >= $argc)
              {
                LOG::failedQuery($format, "not enough arguments for format");
                return false;
              }
            $query = substr_replace($query, $argv[$index_args], $index_query, 2);
            $index_query += strlen($argv[$index_args]);
            $index_args++;
            break;
          default:
            LOG::failedQuery($format, "unknown control sequence '%" . $query[$index_query + 1] . "'");
            return false;
          }
      }

    if ($index_args != $argc)
      {
        LOG::failedQuery($format, "too many arguments for format");
        return false;
      }

    $res = mysqli_query(self::$handle, $query);
    if (!$res)
      LOGDB::failedQuery($query, mysqli_error(self::$handle));

    return $res;
  }
```

Note: the code is mostly untested, chances are, it contains a bunch of bugs. use with caution :)